# Возможно ли сделать JSTL-вставку в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl

Для локализации JSP страниц я использую JSTL-вставки, и это работает прекрасно. Но у меня появилась потребность сделать вставку напрямую в JavaScrypt файл.

Как-то вот так:

```
function (enabled) {
    successNoty(enabled ? <spring:message code="common.enabled"/> : <spring:message code="common.disabled"/>);
}
```

Разумеется, это не работает. Я могу всё-таки сделать вставку каким-то образом? Или это невозможно в принципе?

Я понимаю, что необходимые значения можно передавать как параметры функции, но это будет очень неудобно.

Comment: может вставлять в какой-то узел DOM?

Comment: @AlexandrSolopov вряд ли получиться... функция successNoty не работает со страницей, он просто выводит уведомление. Ей надо получать уже готовый текст.

Comment: Можно обрабатывать js: [How to compile a javascript file as a jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991651/2881286)

Answer (score 0):

Можно `JavaScrypt` файл сделать частью `HTML` файла, т. е. частью `JSP` файла. Например:

```html
<script>
function (enabled) {
    successNoty(enabled ? <spring:message code="common.enabled"/> : <spring:message code="common.disabled"/>);
}
</script>
```

Весь скрипт переносить не обязательно, достаточно только вызовы функций с параметрами.

Comment: Можно. Но я не просто так завёл под js отдельный файл - мне нужно, чтобы в коде ничего не было.

Comment: Так я же написал: _Я понимаю, что необходимые значения можно передавать как параметры функции, но это будет очень неудобно._ . Меня интересует именно возможность вставки jstl напрямую в jsp